# Android: Opening SMS activity with multiple recipients specified

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to start the phone set sms provider by starting an intent. The code I am using below is what I am using to start the intent.

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder("sms:");
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
        uri.append(contacts.get(i).getNumber());
        uri.append(", ");
    }
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri.toString()));
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I specifically want to use this method rather than sending the message myself so the user can use their preferred sms client. I can get it going with just one number but not multiple. I can't find an example anywhere with multiple recipients. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

I tried your approach with little modification and its working properly for me.This is the modified code.

```
StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder("sms:");
    for (int i = 0; i < yourarray.length; i++) {
        uri.append(yourarray[i]);
        uri.append(", ");
    }
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri.toString()));
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Body of Message");
    startActivity(smsIntent);
```